# How to Create animation to create torus from circle?

Tags: tikz-pgf, animations

I have created this:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        
        % big circle
        \draw(2,-1) arc (-90:90:2.5 and 2);% half circle facing left
        \draw(2,-1) arc (-90:90:-2.5 and 2);% half circle facing right
        
        % left circle
        \draw (0.33,-0.5) arc (-90:90:-0.25 and 1.5);% left half of the left circle
        \draw[dashed] (0.33,-0.5) arc (-90:90:0.25 and 1.5);% right half of the left circle
    
        % middle circle
        \draw(2,-1) arc (-90:90:-0.3 and 2);% left half of the middle circle 
        \draw[dashed] (2,-1) arc (-90:90:0.3 and 2);% right half of the middle circle

        % right circle
        \draw (3.67,-0.5) arc (-90:90:-0.25 and 1.5);% left half of the right circle
        \draw[dashed] (3.67,-0.5) arc (-90:90:0.25 and 1.5);% right half of the right circle
                
        %\draw (4,1.5) ellipse (0.5 and 1.5);% a circle / the right ellipse
        \draw (-1.25,1.5) node {$\phi$};
        
        % x ticks
        \draw (-0.7,1) -- (4.7,1);% middle line / diameter
        
        % Right image / Cone
        
        % left circle
        \draw (7.73,0.5) arc (-90:90:-0.25 and 0.5);% left half of the left circle
        \draw[dashed] (7.73,0.5) arc (-90:90:0.25 and 0.5);% right half of the left circle
        
        % middle circle
        \draw(9,0.1) arc (-90:90:-0.3 and 0.9);% left half of the middle circle 
        \draw[dashed] (9,0.1) arc (-90:90:0.3 and 0.9);% right half of the middle circle
        
        % right circle
        \draw (10.88,-0.5) arc (-90:90:-0.35 and 1.5);% left half of the right circle
        \draw (10.88,-0.5) arc (-90:90:0.35 and 1.5);% right half of the right circle
        
        %\draw (4,1.5) ellipse (0.5 and 1.5);% a circle / the right ellipse
        \draw (5.25,1.5) node {$\phi_{2}$};
        
        % upper line / upper pythagoras
        \draw (6,1) -- (10.88,2.5);% middle line / diameter
        
        % lower line / lower pythagoras
        \draw (6,1) -- (10.88,-0.5);% middle line / diameter
         
        % middle line
        \draw (6,1) -- (11.7,1);% middle line / diameter
        
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: mytikz]

2-dimension of regions bounded by semicircle that if it is revolved about the diameter become a cone (figure on the right). Afterwards if it is revolved circling will become a torus.

Can we make the animation of this? Is it achievable to create the animation process from circle to torus.

I am following this example:

[image: example]

I need to color the upper part too.

Comment: When you talk about "the animation of this" do you mean something like an animated `gif` file, or something like your drawing with the cone?  By the way, I don't quite understand that drawing.  For me a semicircle revolved around a diameter leads to a sphere of a portion of a sphere.

Comment: Yes like gif, I want to educate or teach mathematics and its usage. The animation can be a great thing. For simple thing start with a circle then the animation is it is revolving like earth revolved around the sun, then we can see a torus is created.